# mouse-enter event function not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery

I have this image:

```
<img src="..." class="scroller_poster" alt="Some information about movie">
```

... and I'm trying to display the value in ALT in a DIV elsewhere on my page:

```
<div class="scroller_movie_data"></div>
```

... using this function (contained in $(document).ready):

```
$('.scroller_poster').mouseenter(function() {
    var movie_data = $(this).attr('alt');
    if (movie_data) {
        $('.scroller_movie_data').html(movie_data);
        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
            $('.scroller_movie_data').html('');
        });
    }
});
```

This works in all browsers except Firefox and I cannot figure out why. Can somebody shed some light on this please?

**NOTE:**

The image that gets hovered sits inside a jQuery plugin ([SmoothDivScroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com)), which I believe is causing the problem.

Below is a screenshot on what I am working on, it might help understand what I'm doing. Where it says "Madagascar 3: Europe's Most Wanted (2012)" is where I'm trying to get each hovered ALT value to show.

[image]

Comment: Did you check the script console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should'nt rebind the mouseleave function everytime you mouseenter the element, as that will cause the event to be bound multiple times :

```
$(document).on({
     mouseenter: function() {
         var movie_data = $(this).attr('alt');
         if (movie_data.length) $('.scroller_movie_data').html(movie_data);
     },
     mouseleave: function() {
         $('.scroller_movie_data').html('');
     }
}, '.scroller_poster');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BUxHW/)

Comment: Thanks for this but still doesn't fire. It does in your Fiddle example but not in my project. The image that gets 'hovered' in my project is actually inside a jQuery scroller plugin (www.smoothdivscroll.com) - I'm thinking that has a lot to do with it.

Comment: Yes, nearly!! If my cursor is outside of the scroller plugin to start with and then go inside the scroller and hover an image, that movie description does not show, but if I move across one image, it shows correctly and if I move over another it works correctly. If I then take the cursor outside of the scroller, and then go back in and hover another image, it doesn't show again until I move over to the next image.

Comment: Can u suggest how to resolve the last part? You nearly had it with your last update...

Comment: I got it working, so thanks for the push in the right direction. I change `$(document).on` to the scroller element `$('.scroller').on` and changed `'.scroller_poster'` to `'.scroller_poster_item'` which is the parent `<a>` to the image. Seems to be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have the mouseleave event inside the mouseenter event? It's very bad practice and can create multiple event handlers.

Use the hover method in jquery(first function is mouseenter, second function is mouseout):

```
$('.scroller_poster').hover(
  function() {
    var movie_data = $(this).attr('alt');
    if (movie_data)
      $('.scroller_movie_data').html(movie_data);
}, 
  function() {
    $('.scroller_movie_data').html('');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The problem still occurs when trying yours and Adeneo's answer. The image that gets 'hovered' is actually inside a jQuery plugin scroller (www.smoothdivscroll.com) and I'm thinking this is the cause, as works fine in all browsers except Firefox.

Comment: Debug it in firebug. That's the only way to know what's wrong in the plugin.